# Recursively rearrange a flat array into a multi dimensional array

Tags: ruby, algorithm, graph

I'm using the [ruby RGL library](https://github.com/monora/rgl) to save a nested structure and later restore it. Using `graph.edges.as_json` returns the below graph. Where Im stuck at is to turn this array into its nested equivilant.

Example:

```
[{"source"=>1, "target"=>8}, 
 {"source"=>8, "target"=>10}, 
 {"source"=>8, "target"=>13}, 
 {"source"=>8, "target"=>9}, 
 {"source"=>10, "target"=>102}, 
 {"source"=>102, "target"=>103}, 
 {"source"=>102, "target"=>105}, 
 {"source"=>102, "target"=>101}, 
 {"source"=>103, "target"=>104}, 
 {"source"=>104, "target"=>101}, 
 {"source"=>101, "target"=>96}, 
]
```

Needs to turn into:

```
[{source: 1,
  target: [
    {source: 8,
      target: [
        {source: 10,
          target: [
            {source: 102, 
              target: [
                {source: 103,
                  target: [
                    {source: 104,
                      target: [
                        {source: 101,
                          target: [
                            {source: 96,
                              target: []
                          ]}
                        }
                      ]
...
```

Comment: Can we assume that the nodes are always in the right order (aka parents are on the list before their children)?

Comment: Both your input and output data structures seem inefficient and awkward.  Why not use an adjacency matrix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

Comment: @spickermann No they wont be

Comment: I would use a simple hash where the keys are source IDs and the value for each source source ID is a list of target IDs that it points to.  Deeply nested data structures like this will be hard to inspect (i.e. the `inspect` method returns tons of data).  Alternatively, don't use IDs but put references to some custom object type in your hash.

Comment: And you don't need to use an entire third-party library just to save and restore such a graph.  Ruby's built-in JSON or Marshall libraries would work fine for converting the hash to a string or vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the following algorithm. Please refer to the comments within the code for details about how this works.

Specifically, note the usage of the block version of [`Hash.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new) which allows you to set a default value which is set and returned when accessing a key which is not part of the hash.

```
require 'set'

edges = [{"source"=>1, "target"=>8}, 
 {"source"=>8, "target"=>10}, 
 {"source"=>8, "target"=>13}, 
 {"source"=>8, "target"=>9}, 
 {"source"=>10, "target"=>102}, 
 {"source"=>102, "target"=>103}, 
 {"source"=>102, "target"=>105}, 
 {"source"=>102, "target"=>101}, 
 {"source"=>103, "target"=>104}, 
 {"source"=>104, "target"=>101}, 
 {"source"=>101, "target"=>96}, 
]

# Hash which stores the (sub-)trees, using the source id as the key and the tree
# structure as values
graph = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {'source' => k, 'target' => []} }
# Al list of target IDs we have seen. We use this later to remove redundant
# sub-trees
targets = Set.new

edges.each do |edge|
  source = edge['source']
  target = edge['target']

  # For each edge, store it in the graph. We use the predefined structure from
  # the hash to add targets to a source. As we can identify any subtree by its
  # source ID in the graph hash, this even allows us to add multiple targets
  graph[source]['target'] << graph[target]
  targets << target
end

# Cleanup redundant entries, i.e. all those which are referenced in the graph as
# targets. All remaining entries were not targets and are thus roots
targets.each { |target| graph.delete(target) }

# We now have the distinct trees in the graph hash, keyed by their respective
# root source id. To get an array of trees as requested, we can just take the
# values from this hash
trees = graph.values
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably could be cleaned up a bit but it does seem to produce the desired result

```
class EdgeTree 
  attr_reader :edges, :source_groups, :roots, :targets
  def initialize(edges: )
    # store edges
    @edges = edges
    #partition "sources" amd "targets" 
    @roots,@targets = edges.map {|h| h.values_at("source","target")}.transpose
    # remove all "targets" from "sources"
    @targets.each(&roots.method(:delete)) 
    # group edges by "source" for lookup
    @source_groups = edges.group_by {|h| h["source"] }
  end   
   
  # starting points for unique trees
  def root_groups
    @source_groups.slice(*@roots)
  end 

  # accessor method to return desired output 
  # all: true will output all trees from their starting source
  def create_tree(all: false) 
    link(current_group: all ? source_groups : root_groups)
  end
private 
  # recursive method to build the tree
  def link(current_group: nil )
    current_group.map do |k,v|
      {"source" => k, 
       "target" => [*v].map do |h| 
          if source_groups.key?(h["target"])
            link(current_group: source_groups.slice(h["target"]))
          else 
            {"source"=>h["target"], "target" => []}
          end
        end.flatten(1)
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Usage

```
require 'pp'
edges = [{"source"=>1, "target"=>8}, 
 {"source"=>8, "target"=>10}, 
 {"source"=>8, "target"=>13}, 
 {"source"=>8, "target"=>9}, 
 {"source"=>10, "target"=>102}, 
 {"source"=>102, "target"=>103}, 
 {"source"=>102, "target"=>105}, 
 {"source"=>102, "target"=>101}, 
 {"source"=>103, "target"=>104}, 
 {"source"=>104, "target"=>101}, 
 {"source"=>101, "target"=>96}, 
]

pp EdgeTree.new(edges: edges).create_tree
```

Output:

```
[{"source"=>1,
  "target"=>
   [{"source"=>8,
     "target"=>
      [{"source"=>10,
        "target"=>
         [{"source"=>102,
           "target"=>
            [{"source"=>103,
              "target"=>
               [{"source"=>104,
                 "target"=>
                  [{"source"=>101,
                    "target"=>[{"source"=>96, "target"=>[]}]}]}]},
             {"source"=>105, "target"=>[]},
             {"source"=>101, "target"=>[{"source"=>96, "target"=>[]}]}]}]},
       {"source"=>13, "target"=>[]},
       {"source"=>9, "target"=>[]}]}]}]
```

Working Example: https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/EdgeTree

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
  {"source"=>  1, "target"=>  8}, 
  {"source"=>  8, "target"=> 10}, 
  {"source"=>  8, "target"=> 13}, 
  {"source"=>  8, "target"=>  9}, 
  {"source"=> 10, "target"=>102}, 
  {"source"=>102, "target"=>103}, 
  {"source"=>102, "target"=>105}, 
  {"source"=>102, "target"=>101}, 
  {"source"=>103, "target"=>104}, 
  {"source"=>104, "target"=>101}, 
  {"source"=>101, "target"=> 96} 
]
```

---

First create a hash that maps the first instance of each node to the following node.

```
s_to_t = arr.uniq { |g| g["source"] }.map(&:values).to_h
  #=> {1=>8, 8=>10, 10=>102, 102=>103, 103=>104, 104=>101, 101=>96}
```

Note that the first part of this calculation is as follows.

```
arr.uniq { |g| g["source"] }
  #=> [
  #     {"source"=>  1, "target"=>  8},
  #     {"source"=>  8, "target"=> 10},
  #     {"source"=> 10, "target"=>102},
  #     {"source"=>102, "target"=>103},
  #     {"source"=>103, "target"=>104},
  #     {"source"=>104, "target"=>101},
  #     {"source"=>101, "target"=> 96}
  #   ]
```

---

Next, determine the source node, which is the key that does not appear as a value, assuming there is exactly one key having that property, which is the case with the example.

```
first_source = (s_to_t.keys - s_to_t.values).first
  #=> 1
```

---

Now create a recursive method.

```
def recurse(node, s_to_t)
  ["source"=> node,
   "target"=> s_to_t.key?(node) ? recurse(s_to_t[node], s_to_t) : []
  ]
end
```

---

Let's try it.

```
recurse(first_source, s_to_t)
  #=> [
  #     {"source"=>1, "target"=>[
  #       {"source"=>8, "target"=>[
  #         {"source"=>10, "target"=>[
  #           {"source"=>102, "target"=>[
  #             {"source"=>103, "target"=>[
  #               {"source"=>104, "target"=>[
  #                 {"source"=>101, "target"=>[
  #                   {"source"=>96, "target"=>[]
  #                   }
  #                  ]
  #                 }
  #                ]
  #               }
  #              ]
  #             }
  #            ]
  #           }
  #          ]
  #         }
  #        ]
  #       }
  #      ]
  #     }
  #   ]
```